# Как переопределить стили формы менеджера паролей встроенного в chrome?

Tags: javascript, css3, google-chrome, firefox

Например есть форма

```css
.form fieldset input[type=text]:focus{
   color: red;
   font-weight;
}
```

```html
<form>
  
  
<fieldset class="col-12 col-lg-4">
  <div class="input--text">
    <input class="text-" type="text" name="name" />
  </div>
</fieldset>



<fieldset class="col-12 col-lg-4">
  <div class="input--text">
    <input class="text-" type="text" name="fio" />
  </div>
</fieldset>


</form>
```

Т.е если я хочу заверстать обычный фокус инпута, то это будет работать только в случае если удалить автозаполняемое поле и начать набирать текст заново.

Какие есть варианты? Скорее всего эти менеджеры паролей юзает большинство пользователей, но верстка при автозаполнении стремная ( оранжевый бекграунд, шрифты и т.д). Ааналогично в яндекс браузере, firefox

Comment: http://skrinshoter.ru/s/110919/5ZleGRqe?a

Answer (score 2):

Вы имеете ввиду стиль поля после того, как выбрали один из вариантов из списка автозаполнения? Если да, то для webkit браузеров можно так. Тут фон перекрываем внутренней тенью.

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px yellow inset;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  
  
<fieldset class="col-12 col-lg-4">
  <div class="input--text">
    <input class="text-" type="text" name="name" />
  </div>
</fieldset>



<fieldset class="col-12 col-lg-4">
  <div class="input--text">
    <input class="text-" type="text" name="fio" />
  </div>
</fieldset>


</form>
```

Comment: Вроде того, а точнее ДО того как что то вообще выбрали, когда на сайт например, уже заходили и логин вписан сразу при загрузке страницы

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко этот способ тоже подходит для такого случая